# Where do [svn] server configuration/administration questions belong?

Tags: discussion, scope

I haunt the [svn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/svn) tag and *so many* of the questions are along the lines of one of the following:

> How do I configure my SVN server to do (some custom behavior)?
>
> How do I get (some tool) to interoperate with my SVN server?
>
> How do I perform (some administrative task) on my SVN server?

Some examples from the last *6 hours*:

- [Can't SVN checkout repository; Server doesn't receive request](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27532275/1698557)
- [Cannot Connect to Subversion (SVN) on AWS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27531608/1698557)
- [Migrating SVN Repository authentication store and logins](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27533824/1698557)
- [VisualSVN Server repo folder not accessible after being shared](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27526869/1698557)

These questions are technically on-topic since they are asking about a programming tool, but I don't think they fit the spirit of that provision of the on-topic guidelines.

However, these questions on SO generally have a small chance of being answered successfully because (in my experience) it's generally programmers who administrate their repositories and find themselves out of their depth when they need to do anything beyond setting up the repository.

I've tried redirecting some of them to ServerFault or even SuperUser when appropriate, but honestly I'm not sure they belong there either.  ServerFault seems to want to be only for server administrators, and judging by the content of these questions they don't appear to be professional admins.

So, what to do?  I'd hate to have to close-vote every third question in the tag and not leave them with a viable alternative site to ask at.  But by leaving them open they seem to languish for some time before either being self-answered or unsuccessfully answered.

Comment: `These questions are technically on-topic since they are asking about a programming tool` They have to be about a specific *programming issue* using a programming tool. So if it doesn't have a specific programming issue then it is off-topic